# Play sound with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a table with string and button(that play sound) in each row and every button play a different sound.

i want to do it with this method :

```
<script>
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
  var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
  thissound.Play();
}
</script>

<embed src="success.wav" autostart=false width=1 height=1 id="sound1"
enablejavascript="true">
```

and this is the button:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Play Sound" onClick="EvalSound('sound1')">
</form>
```

the problem is that i want here :

```
<input type="button" value="Play Sound" onClick="EvalSound('sound1')">
```

to write the file URL instead of 'sound1', it is possible to do it in this way? or i need to change another stuff in the code?

## Edit :

i build the script like this:

```
<script>
   function EvalSound(soundobj) {
   var embed = document.createElement('embed');
   embed.setAttribute('width',1);
   embed.setAttribute('height',1);
   embed.setAttribute('src',soundobj);
   embed.setAttribute('autostart', false);
   embed.setAttribute('enablejavascript', true);
   embed.Play();
   }
</script>
```

and call this with :

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Play Sound" onClick="EvalSound('sound url')">
</form>
```

and it still not play the sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it as follow:

refer blog [How to Play a Sound on Click or on MouseOver](http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function playSound(soundfile) {
 document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
 "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
 }
 </script>
```

In web page

```
<span id="dummy"></span>
<a href="#" onclick="playSound('URL to soundfile');">Click here to hear a sound</a>

 <p onmouseover="playSound('URL to soundfile');">Mouse over this text to hear a sound</p>
```

Comment: Don't forget to check this page, beacause that solution removes the text associated with the anchor: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/49572-play-sound-on-click/

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This is not HTML5.
You could get the source with `thissound.src`. Then you can add it to the DOM in whichever location you would like to put it at.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a javascript framework to make your code easier. Take a look at the Scriptaculous page:

http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/sound/

To my knowledge 'jQuery' is not so well appointed for sound, however, I guess that there are plugins for that.

Then you could put your sound files as links or 'rel' links, have observers on the buttons and play them with quite clean HTML and a little scripting.