# Play sound with javascript not work

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want I want to create a table with images that each play a different sound when clicked.
when I created a JavaScript function in a simple page, it worked but when I put it in my page not work without table just sentence.

Then, I tried that again but it did not work ..

```
<span id="dummy"> </span> <table> <tr><td> <td> <a  onclick="playSound('/img/letter/sound/a.mp3');"><img src="./img/letter/aa.jpg"/><p>Apple</p></a></td></tr>...........</table>
```

JavaScript

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function playSound(soundfile) {
  document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML+
    "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>
```

from here I tried :
[Play sound with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078933/play-sound-with-javascript)

[WebDesign Play Sound](http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm)

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: @Evan Knowles .. not error but it didn't run sound

Comment: @EvanKnowles Do you know why?

Comment: You'd probably be better off using the more modern HTML5 audio.

Comment: are you sure your mp3 location is true? change and test it :  http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Canon.mp3

Comment: @apsuva it is work thank you when I added your sound. but when I change to add different sounds.. all <td> sounds work the same time

Comment: it must refresh page after each sound. why ?

Comment: @Dalal http://fiddle.jshell.net/v7KV2/5/ check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is working. but script must be after your html code.

and sound repeat problem is solved. you must change your script.

```
function playSound(soundfile) {
var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = 
"<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" id=\"myAudio\" />";

console.log("audio src " ,audie.src);
console.log("file ", soundfile);

if( audie.src == soundfile){ 
    audie.paused ? audie.play() : audie.pause();

}else{
     audie.src = soundfile;
     audie.play();
}
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/v7KV2/5/

Comment: it must refresh page after each sound. why? it is normal or not?

Comment: it need 15 reputation but I haven't :""(

Comment: @Dalal dont need up vote. check correct answer : http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png